# Going to app using more menu from google no longer working for old marketplace app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have an application listed in the old google apps marketplace and when our customers try to go to our app using the 'More' menu in google (nine dots icon), then they now get a 400 Bad Request during the redirection process. This was working until recently and nothing has changed on our end.

I take it that going to an app from more menu is still suppose to work for apps on the old google apps marketplace. Can some google person take a look and see why it is not working any more?

When I click on our application in the more menu we are taken to an url like this (I've changes some of the actual values in the url below to post here for security reasons) and get 400 Bad Request:

```
https://apis.google.com/additnow/l?applicationid=xxx&__ls=ogb&__lu=https%3A%2F%2Fusqa.blah.us%2Fblah-usqa%2Fpages%2FgoogleAppsMarketplace%2FgoogleAppsNavLink.html%3Ffrom%3Dgoogle%26domain%3Dblahblah.com&token=yyy
```

Regards,
LT

Comment: I tested again today and things seem to be working again. So hopefully it was just an intermittent issue on the google side.

Answer (score -2):

This issue should be fixed now. Let us know on this forum if this is still an issue.

Apoorv - Product Manager Google Apps marketplace.